# font family in LaTeX

Tags: fonts

The image below is from ConText. Does anyone know what the family font it is from in LaTeX?

Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Do you have the PDF file? You can see the font name in the properties.

Comment: Please provide at **least** a link to the PDF in question and not a only a blurry screenshot.